# Parquet using s3a in Spark 1.6

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet

I need to access **Parquet** files on **S3** from **Spark 1.6**.  My attempted approach is at the bottom, and I get a "**403 Forbidden**" error, which is the same error as if the keys are invalid or missing.

Historically, I've done that using the deprecated s3n with keys in-line:

```
s"s3n://${key}:${secretKey}@${s3_bucket}"
```

For all the well-documented reasons, s3n and this format is problematic.

When I access **JSON** from **Spark 1.6**, this **works**...

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint",  "s3.amazonaws.com")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", key)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secretKey)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")

val fg = "s3a://bucket/folder/dt=" + day
val rdd = sc.textFile(fg)
```

When I access **Parquet** from **Spark 2.x**, this **works**...

```
val spark = {
  SparkSession.builder //()
  .config("fs.s3a.access.key", key)
  .config("fs.s3a.secret.key", secretKey)
  .config("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
  .getOrCreate()
}

val fg = "s3a://bucket/folder/dt=" + day
val parqet = spark.read.parquet(fg)
```

My best guess for **Parquet** from **Spark 1.6** would be something like this, but I get a **403 Forbidden error**...

```
sqlContext.setConf("fs.s3a.access.key", key)
sqlContext.setConf("fs.s3a.secret.key", secretKey)
sqlContext.setConf("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")

val fg = "s3a://bucket/folder/dt=" + day
val parq = sqlContext.read.parquet(fg)    // 403 Forbidden here
```

Any advice appreciated.

**EDIT** - adding some detail about other s3a settings.

```
// sqlContext.getAllConfs.filter(_._1 contains "s3a").foreach(println)
(fs.s3a.connection.maximum,15)
(fs.s3a.impl,org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem)
(fs.s3a.fast.buffer.size,1048576)
(fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey,DikembeMutombo)
(fs.s3a.connection.timeout,50000)
(fs.s3a.buffer.dir,${hadoop.tmp.dir}/s3a)
(fs.s3a.endpoint,s3.amazonaws.com)
(fs.s3a.paging.maximum,5000)
(fs.s3a.threads.core,15)
(fs.s3a.multipart.purge,false)
(fs.s3a.threads.max,256)
(fs.s3a.multipart.threshold,2147483647)
(fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId,DikembeMutombo)
(fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled,true)
(fs.s3a.connection.establish.timeout,5000)
(fs.s3a.threads.keepalivetime,60)
(fs.s3a.max.total.tasks,1000)
(fs.s3a.fast.upload,false)
(fs.s3a.attempts.maximum,10)
(fs.s3a.multipart.size,104857600)
(fs.s3a.multipart.purge.age,86400)
```

**EDIT 2** - adding the workaround I'm using if I can't solve.

I think I have two options that I can make work, but I don't care for either.

- s3a with credentials either hard-coded in core-site.xml OR set dynamically using sqlContext.setConf()...  does **not work**.
- s3a with credentials inline in the URL...  **works**.
- s3 with credentials set via sqlContext.setConf()...  does **not work**.
- s3 with credentials hard-coded in core-site.xml...  **works**.

Unfortunately...  including credentials in-line is bad security practice (and creates problems)...  but hard-coding in core-site.xml isn't a complete solution.  I need to be able to toggle between 4 sets of credentials.  So my hack-y solution is to hard code s3 credentials in core-site.xml...  and use inline with s3a to access Parquet in other AWS environments.

Would rather use s3a only and never with inline credentials, but I can't get that to work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging auth problems is hard as everyone goes out of their way to not log the secrets.

I'd start with the [Troubleshooting S3A](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/#Troubleshooting_S3A) documentation.

Here I think the issue is that the name of the secret and access key was changed in s3a to `fs.s3a.access.key` and `fs.s3a.secret.key`

Set them and hopefully your problems will go away.

I agree with your goal of not putting secrets inline; in Hadoop 2.8+ the s3a connector will warn you against secrets-in-URLs, because it's hard to keep them out of logs.

Comment: appreciate the feedback.  hadoop can authenticate fine already.  the problem is something in SqlContext (can't authenticate) vs SparkContext (can authenticate) as the entry point, which is outside the scope of this hadoop doc.